# Initialize custom object property as undefined with type?

Tags: typescript

I am initialiting my custom typescript object like this:

```
{
    game: false ? new Game() : undefined,
}
```

While this does allow typescript to infer the type of this attribute, I had to disable a useful eslint rule. This also doesn't seem like the intended way to do this. Is there a better way?

Comment: `const o = {
    game: undefined as Game|undefined,
};` ?

Comment: why dont you define the type of your object beforehand ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the game property conditionally.

```
const obj = {
  ...(condition && { game: new Game() })
};

console.log(obj.game);
```

Now if the `condition` is true it should have the game property, and if the condition is false it should return undefined.

To please the eslint you can define the Object type with optional game property and assign it to your object.

```
interface Object {
  game?: GameType;
}

const obj: Object = {
...(condition && { game: new Game() })
};
```